# ServerCertificateValidationCallback is not being called for a revoked certificate

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, httpwebrequest

I'm writing code to alert the user once he gives a URL with an invalid certificate as input.

I'm using the following code to do so:

```
     HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
     request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
     response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

ServerCertificateValidationCallback is being called for expired certificate/unsigned/untrusted
But for a revoked certificate URL, ServerCertificateValidationCallback is not being called.

Is it normal for this code or am I missing something?

Comment: It is normal.  The exception is being picked up internal in the HttpWebRequest and not being forward up to your application.

Comment: Why is that so? Is no way for me to have a call back function for a website with a revoked certificate?

Comment: It is the Microsoft design of the class.  Look at the source : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/